# Which parts of C# .NET framework are actually parts of the language?

Tags: c#

I am wondering which parts of the `System` are language features (core components), and which parts are just useful filler, but aren't strictly necessary. I may be off with the wording here, so let me illustrate with an example what I mean.

Consider `System.Console` class it's obviously something that is used for something very particular. In essence, this thing is there to play nice with a feature of Windows / current OS. It's not what I would call a core component of the language.

On the other hand, take the `System.IDisposable` interface. That thing's obviously very important, as without it the `using()` statement is useless. A class needs to implement this particular interface for a language feature to kick in.

I could assume that the `mscorlib` is the responsible party here. A quick glance with the Object explorer shows that it indeed houses many of the components I can agree are core, while at the same time it puts the `Console` class into System namespace, which is just filler.

This notion of placing filler and language-specific objects into the same namespace equates them, but for a deeper understanding of C#, I would like to know which is which. So, I'm looking for a list of core components of C#. I'm assuming that there's a handy reference somewhere, but since I was asleep during the google-lecture I was unable to form the correct query to find it.

Thanks in advance.

**Much later EDIT** I read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx) Lippert blog post, it's kind-of-related. Interestingly `foreach` construct doesn't actually require `IEnumerable` interface to function.

Comment: As far as I know languages like C# and Objective-C are just some syntax with a Math library and some core functions like if statements and loops. There is some language level stuff, but they rely heavily on the frameworks they're designed for. Objective C would be C with different syntax and design patterns without Cocoa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There aren't *very* many types actually required by C#. Ones which I can think of off the top of my head and with a quick check of the spec:

- System.Object
- System.Enum
- System.ValueType
- The primitive types: System.{Int16,Int32,Int64,UInt16,UInt32,UInt64,Byte,SByte,Double,Single,Char,Boolean}
- System.String
- System.Decimal
- System.Nullable<T>
- System.Array
- System.Exception (and various subclasses - see section 16.4 of the spec)
- System.Delegate (and possibly System.MulticastDelegate)
- System.IDisposable
- System.Attribute (and some specific attributes, such as ConditionalAttribute and ObsoleteAttribute)
- System.Type
- System.Collections.IEnumerable / IEnumerator
- System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> / IEnumerator<T>
- System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>
- System.Threading.Monitor
- System.Threading.Interlocked
- System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<T>
- Task and Task<T> for C# 5
- System.GC (mentioned in the spec, but not explicitly used by the compiler AFAIK)

Now any target framework is going to require more types than that for the *implementation* of course - things like `MethodInfo` as mentioned in comments, probably attributes to decorate out parameters (and a whole *bunch* of other types for dynamic typing). But different target systems could have different implementations of that - you couldn't depend on them when writing truly portable C#.

Comment: And System.Monitor (for `lock`)

Comment: And `Type` for `typeof(...)`.

Comment: System.Type for typeof(XYZ).  Similarly, `Delegate` and probably at least MethodInfo for implicit delegate construction.  I suspect most `Type`-related reflection types should be in here since Type and MethodInfo depend on these, but it's not unavoidable, I suppose, if you redefine them.

Comment: @Eamon: Type I agree with. Delegate I've already got. MethodInfo isn't mentioned in the spec though. The target framework would have to have *something* like that, but it wouldn't have to have the same name, etc.

Comment: How 'bout Enumerable, Queryable and IQueryable?  they're not *required* - but a pretty major language feature is rather unfinished without them... - this would be in a category of "grey area" - possibly not explicitly in the spec by implicitly they or something semantically equivalant almost have to be (like MethodInfo).

Comment: Hmmm - I still can't find the "fixed" spec; pretty sure I've seen it though :) maybe I had the updated version direct...

Comment: @Eamon: Not necessarily - you could use Edulinq for example :) It's a *design feature* that LINQ is based on patterns rather than on any particular implementation of that pattern.

Comment: @Eamon - not mentioned in the spec, and you can write a full LINQ API without them

Comment: @Eamon since Linq works just on method names it doesn't need to give special treatment to `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable`. `IEnumerable` of course gets special treatment by other language features(iterators), but I don't think `IQueryable` does.

Comment: `Func<...>` is mentioned in 4.6, but only as example

Comment: ObsoleteAttribute and maybe a few others

Comment: @Marc I would consider both Func<> and Action<>, but I don't think they hinge any particular language feature...

Comment: @Gleno - I mention because it **is** in the official spec - but not as a requirement; the attributes I mention, however, **are** formal spec elements

Comment: @Marc, @Jon: the EduLinq implementation rather proves my point: you may not need the Enumerable implementation, but you do need something virtually identical to be able to reasonably use LINQ.

Comment: @Marc: the spec is not a complete definition of the language in a usable form.  It doesn't define the details of most classes referenced in the list above - and that's essentially what the questioner is asking, right?  What (.NET) types are needed to complete that definition?  Only including types that are *directly* referenced simply opens *new* holes, namely those types that are referenced by one level of indirection.

Comment: `IList<>` - array is defined to be implicitly convertable to `IList<>`.

Comment: and how could we forget `StackOverflowException` ;-)

Comment: @Eamon: There are *lots* of types which are needed to make the language useful, but they could be implemented in different ways for different frameworks. It's pretty useless to have a platform without stream handling, but that's not part of the *language*.

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive list. It would seem that the only way to find out the answer to my question is to go through the spec and see if a particular type has been mentioned. This tastes weird in my mouth, but I'll have to live with it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe looking for types that are 'core' to the language is the wrong starting point.

Any .NET application is run by the CLR so the more important perspective is "what are the essential parts/classes of the CLR" .

And that really goes for understanding C# too.

Comment: I don't think that all the core-components of C# are necessarily core compoents of CRL, although I would admit a very generous overlap. Off the top of my head, I would imagine that Nullable<T> is implemented in CLR rather than being a special case, but in C# it hinges the questionmark synthax.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is special for the runtime too. In particular its boxing behavior.

Comment: There are feature in the CLR that's not accessible when writing in C#

Answer (score 1):

- `Expression` classes(not only `Expression<T>`) since C# can convert lambdas to expressions
- `IEnumerator`, `IEnumerator<T>` used by both `foreach` and the `yield`-iterators
- A few magic attributes, to support the keywords `dynamic`, `params`, `out` and extension-methods
- `System.Type`

Comment: While the compiler *does* use attributes to decorate dynamic, params etc, I don't believe they're part of the spec - so different target platforms may use different types.

Comment: Yes I'm listing types here which get special treatment by the common implementations of the C# compiler, and not only those that are required by the spec.

Comment: IEnumerator is not strictly needed for the foreach to work, since it's pattern based.

Comment: `foreach` is not *exclusively* pattern based. In particular it will work if `GetEnumerator()` is an explicit interface implementation of `IEnumerator<T>`. The specification basically says first perform a pattern match and if that fails fall back to the interfaces. So these interfaces are indeed special cased in the `foreach` compiler code, and the specification of `foreach` explicitly mentions them.