# What types are required by C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, f#, base-class-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which parts of C# .NET framework are actually parts of the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836141/which-parts-of-c-net-framework-are-actually-parts-of-the-language)

There are some features of C# that require specific type (“the type has to implement `System.IDisposable`”). Other features are based on patterns (“any type that has something that looks like a method called `Select()` with the proper signature”).

What is the minimum set of types that C# requires from the library (the former case above)? How does that differ from other languages like VB.NET and F#?

Comment: I remember seeing a similar question recently... looking

Comment: I'm sure I've answered this before, but I'm blowed if I can find it right now...

Comment: @Jon - yes, I remember we kept adding things like ObsoleteAttribute, ConditionalAttribute etc

Comment: @Henk - yes, that's the one, ta

Comment: @Henk: Well spotted. that's the one I was thinking of :)

Comment: Thanks all, I suspected the question could be already answered, but couldn't find it myself.

Answer (score -2):

IDisposable is an interface, .Net provivdes interfaces as a means to develop contract based APIs rather than relying on concrete classes. Eg, It lets you say, 'any type as long as it has a method called Dispose()'

This is nothing much to do with the C# type system nor it's primitive types.

Comment: "Any type as long as it has a method called `Dispose()`" is different from "any type that implements `IDisposable`".

Comment: It has everything to do with the C# type system, as the C# spec requires it for the `using` statement. That's the point of the question: if you were to implement the C# spec on a different platform, which types would you *have* to have?