# What are the types in C# that the syntax depends on?

Tags: c#, syntax, clr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which parts of C# .NET framework are actually parts of the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836141/which-parts-of-c-sharp-net-framework-are-actually-parts-of-the-language)

I know it uses

- `System.Type` like in `typeof(foo)`
- `System.Attribute` because you can use `[Foo]` instead of `[FooAttribute]`
- `System.String` because you can write `"bla".ToLower()`.
- `System.Exception` because `throw obj` only works with this type or inheriting types.
- `System.Array` obviously
- and all the built in value types `int`,`decimal`, `bool` etc.

Are there any others?

Comment: `"bla"` itself is a `System.String`. All literal values have their own types.

Comment: Ok, but that is a essentially different because it is inferred from syntax in another way than using `string`. `int` is the same because you can have `i++`. `System.DateTime` doesn't have this property.

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to know this?

Comment: Just curiuos and it has always been a dream of mine to get an answer/comment from @Eric Lippert

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard question. Well, I'll start with the literal values that you can write in the source code that doesn't require evaluation at runtime:

- string `"String"`
- char `'c'`
- REAL VALUETYPES `decimal`, `float`, `double`
- INTEGRAL VALUETYPES `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong` (`short`, `ushort`, `byte`, and `sbyte` are all supported keywords also, but they require a cast, unlike these four)
- bool (`true` | `false`) (also implicitly used in evaluations such as `a == b` or `c < d`)
- `null` literal (not actually a type, but I put it here in the interest of completeness because it can represent any and all reference types.)

Now, language constructs:

- arrays `bool[]` `char[]` `float[]` *etc* (support all types shown above except *null* plus all user-defined types
- nullable `bool?` `char?` `float?` *etc* (boxes valuetypes to allow the extra value *null*)
- `typeof(T)` - as you said, returns Type, so c# language supports the Type type. Also, for every single object reference or value type, you can call GetType() on it to retrieve the same thing - this is inherited from *object*.
- `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerator`, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` for foreach and query expressions
- `System.Threading.Monitor` for lock () statements
- `Func<T>`, `Func<T1, T2, ... TN>`, `Action`, `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2, ... TN>` for lambda expressions.
- `IDisposable` interface for using() statements
- `Exception` class for catch (ExceptionClassType) {} clauses in try statements.

I'll update with more when I think of them.

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand your question, you want to create a list of pre-defined classes that the C# compiler needs to be aware of to support C# language features.

From the top of my head, I'd add the following:

- `System.Object`, the base class,
- `System.ValueType`, from which all `struct`s inherit,
- `System.Delegate`, the base class for delegate types.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand the question, but...

`System.IDisposable` only works with `using(var myDisposable = new MyDisposable()){...}`, where `MyDisposable` implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to the list:

`IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerator<T>` as the return type of a method or property with `yield break` and/or  `yield return` must be one of those types, and the compiler-generated class will implement it.

I'll disagree with the logic of:

> `System.Attribute` because you can use `[Foo]` instead of `[FooAttribute]`

As that is just some sugar that means that if an attribute's name ends with "Attribute" and there isn't another attribute whose name is the same as it without "Attribute", then you can omit that bit. `System.Attribute` is still an example though, since you cannot use an object for an attribute unless it's descended from it.

Comment: Thank You. Regarding `Attribute`, your logic is better.